# OpenStreetMap to pgRouting missing attributes?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

We are trying routing with pgrouting for our project but we noticed that NOT all the attributes we had in the row OSM data are in our database after we imported the data. we have checked in the original OSM file that the attribute tages are there but not in the database after using osm2pgrouting tool.  we followed the tutorial in http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html . we needed the attributes tags like traffic_signals, lit.

have you ever experienced this problem?

could it be from osm2pgrouting conversion tool?

Comment: Proper formatting and paragraphs make it easier to read your question. We take a time to answer your question, so we also expect that you take a time to ask properly! Capitalization: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/592/01/

Answer (score 3):

OSM attributes can vary a lot, so attributes used in osm2pgrouting are commonly used and available in general. Because there can be so many different attributes, it's not possible (and not a good idea) to import them all.

There are tools, which can do this better, for example [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) or [Imposm](http://imposm.org/). osm2pgrouting imports the `osm_id` attribute, so you should be able to link the tables afterwards.